# How can I get the attribute value of an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is a demo code:

```
<div id="demo" myAttribute="ok"></div>
```

Here are 2 things I want
1) the attribute name, ie: 'myAttribute'.
2) the element that contains the attribute 'myAttribute', ie: the div.

Comment: For these types of questions, you usually get a better response if you start off with what you've tried and ask a more specific question about the issue you've run into. At the very least, explain why existing solutions (of which there are many) aren't working in your case. A specification document for the code you want isn't quite in the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of *Nodes* that match a selector

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[myAttribute]');
```

`list` will be *Array-like* but not inherit from *Array*. You can loop over it with `for` and `list.length`

---

To get a [*NamedNodeMap*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) of the *attributes* on an *Element*

```
var nnm = elem.attributes;
```

`nnm` will be *Array-like* but not inherit from *Array*. You can loop over it with `for` and `nnm.length`

---

To get the *value* of an *attribute* on an *Element* use [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
var val = elem.getAttribute('myAttribute');
```

`val` will be `null` if there is no such *attribute*

---

To test the existance of an *attribute* on an *Element* use [`.hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)

```
var b = elem.hasAttribute('myAttribute');
```

`b` will be a *Boolean* value, `true` or `false`

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you could do something like this.

```
div = $("[myAttribute]");
attrValue = div.attr('myAttribute');
```

`div` would be the jQuery element.
`attrValue` would be 'ok'

Comment: The question is using  Pure Javascript.

Comment: @HarshaVardhini 2015?

Comment: what about 2015?

Comment: SO is so weird. I have been around for a while and people are seriously crazy about the guidelines. I believe I had 16 reputation points when I wrote this answer. Yes, I misread the question, but I was still new to the game. In my heart I did not mean to offend anybody by answering the question poorly, I just meant to help. I can see why the site gets criticism. Anyway, I apologize for misreading this question and please feel free to downvote this question some more. It won’t keep me from trying to help in the future.